# How To Get Alexa Sites Linking Using PHP

Tags: php, api, alexa

I am planning to get the Alexa sites linking of a given website.

I am looking to do this in PHP. Please suggest me is Alexa providing any API. Is there any tool? Is it free? Is there any API that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Alexa has an [API](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/awis/) for this kind of stuff but it's not free.

Here's a [tutorial](http://tutology.net/category/how-php/get-alexa-rank-php-and-alexa-api) to get data from this API with PHP.